# Firefox not rendering line-height from .less file

Tags: css, less

I may be missing something hilariously simple, but I can't spot my mistake

Essentially, I'm creating a template for a new web app, using LESS for the stylesheets. In Chrome, Opera and Safari the line-height works perfectly fine, however in Firefox, it doesn't render. Briefly this is the code I've got

templates.less

```
@content-header-height:         calc(@content-header-font-size * 3);
@content-header-line-height:    calc(@content-header-font-size * 3 - 1px);

.header {
   height: @content-header-height;
   line-height: @content-header-line-height;
}
```

There are more properties obviously but these are the relevant ones. In Firefox, the line-height property doesn't even appear.

Comment: What does the generated CSS look like?

Comment: When you say "the line-height property doesn't even appear", do you mean that Firefox dev tools doesn't show this CSS property on relevant elements?

Comment: I'm guessing that it's an issue with Firefox's support for `calc()`.

Comment: @NicolasMcCurdy yes, in the dev tools I see the height show up as height: calc(42px); however there isn't even an entry for the line-height. In Chrome dev tools it's there and working fine, which makes me think it's ok with the calc function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need the `calc` there? try removing it.

Comment: Good lord you are my new hero! Worked a treat, knew it would be something easy I was overlooking, thanks a lot

Comment: and what if you _need_ it?  firefox doesn't appear to even support calc on line-heights....